# Dropzone.js : add already stored files not triggering events

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I'm using dropzone.js and node.js to add an easy drag-and-drop interface for a user to upload up to 10 photos to server. 
Here is my init function:

```
init: function(){
                var photos = $('#property-photo').data('photos').split(',');
                for (var i = 0; i < photos.length; i++) {
                    var photo = "/photo/" + photos[i];
                    var mockFile= {type: "image/*", name: 'photo', size: 1500};
                    this.addFile.call(this, mockFile);
                    this.options.thumbnail.call(this, mockFile, photo);
                }

            }
```

The thumbnail is shown but when i call `listingDropzone.processQueue();` - it throws an error:

> Failed to execute 'append' on 'FormData': No function was found that
>   matched the signature provided.

Only if i remove the image and add a new one it works.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Dropzone can't upload a mock file. Mock file was already uploaded.
You can see this issue: https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/418

Comment: Can you explain a little more about why "this" might work? Give a little context?